# How to fix Error while loading shared libraries - when uusing eclipse share project

Tags: c++, eclipse

I'm using eclipse (& Linux).
In eclipse I have 2 C++ projects (in the same worksapce):
1. ShrPrj (which I compile as share library)
2. MainPrj (which is exe proj and it use the ShrPrj project)

I can compile those 2 projects,
but when I'm trying to run MainPrj I'm getting the following error:
error while loading shared libraries ShrPrj...

How can I setup & config the MainPrj eclipse project to load the share library (of the second eclipse project) ?
It seems that in the LD_LIBRARY_PATH I cant setreference to other project

Comment: Do you want to *link* with the shared library when building? Or do you want to load the shared library *at run-time* when the main program is running?

Comment: I can link it (because I can compile it). I want to load the share library in runtime (when ruuing the MainPrj from eclipse)

Comment: If you want to load the library dynamically at run-time, it has nothing to do with the IDE or building, but it's all how you have coded the loading. Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us how you load the shared library. Also tell us what errors (the codes, numeric or symbolic) you get from the functions you use.